# React route like facebook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement the route like facebook. Let me explain how some route works on Facebook, When a user is scrolling through his feed at home page, `Url is example.com/` then if user clicked any photo in the feed a modal will appear over the feed and the url will change like `example.com/photo/?urlparams`. When user click the back button or close button, Modal hides itself and url back to previous home page `example.com/` without re-rendering the feed.

What I tried is

```
         <Route path='/' exact render={(props) => <PostLists {...props} scroll={scroll} /> } />
         <Route path='/post/:id'  render={(props) => <Single {...props} scroll={scroll}/> } />
```

PostLists component has infinte scroll so may have up to 90+ posts. Each post have `Link` to Single Component like below

```
        <Link to={`/post/${props.post.slug}`} className={`post-title`}>{pTitle}</Link>
```

Everthing works fine like normal navigation. But I like to show this Single Component in the Modal over the PostsLits Component, by the same time URL should be changed like `example.com/post/url-slug`

So I replaced `Link` in the post's title as

```
<span onClick={titleClick} className={`post-title`}>{pTitle}</span>
const titleClick = () => {
    props.toggle(true) //Modal Toggle
    return  window.history.pushState(null, null, `/post/${props.post.slug}`) 
}
```

This works like what I expected but I'm using `window history` not the react's history so I cannot listen to the URL change from browser back button. If I click the back button URL changes to previous `example.com/` But I'm unable to hide the Modal.

What I want is Every post can have `(example.com/post/slug)`seperate page to display their content, But when clicking the post from Home Page it should be displayed as Modal and url should change to their respective post url `example.com/post/slug` on clicking the back button modal should be hidden and PostLists should be displayed.

Comment: From what I can understand of this question, you want to match multiple routes simultaneously. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code, specifically starting with your routes component. The `exact` prop on "/" means as soon as the path is *anything but* "/" it will not render, but this is just the start from the shared snippet, the `Router` and anything between can affect what is rendered.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks man. Being a rookie I'm unaware of matching multiple routes. After your comment got an idea and modified examples from reacttraining. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery